# How to check whether the link is clicked or not in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a link,on clicking the link it displays a text field and a submit button,when i input 'ALLUSERS' in the text filed and click on the submit button,it should clear the contents in the text filed and display a pop up saying invalid input,how do i do this in javascript,i am new to javascript so kindly help me.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function checklink() {
    if (document.getElementById("report420").click == true) {
        if (document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value == 'ALLUSERS') {
            document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value = "";
            alert("invalid input");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be saying the link that displays the field and button works, so please show your existing code for that part. (And why have you tagged your question with "java" and "jsp" if you're asking how to do this in JavaScript?)

Comment: function checklink()
{
 if(document.getElementById("report420").click==true)
  {
  
  if(document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value=='ALLUSERS')
  {
  document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value="";
  alert("invalid input");
  }
  
  
}

Comment: You can add more information to your question by clicking the "edit" link. I've added the code from your comment for you - note that it is missing the closing `}` from the function, and you don't say how that function is called.

Comment: my bad,the function is called on click of the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var link = document.getElementById('report420');
    link.addEventListener('click', continueScript);
    function continueScript(){
        var el = document.getElementById('mainUserIdValue');
        if(el.value == 'ALLUSERS'){
            el.value = '';
            alert('Invalid input');
        }
        /* Continue your code here */
    }
};
```

**A quick explanation on `addEventListener`:**
The method `addEventListener` is used to trigger a function when a certain criteria is met. In this example the criteria is that the element to which the method is applied is clicked on by the user.
When the user clicks on the link with the ID of `report420` the function `continueScript` is called, from there you can do anything you want. Note that the function is passed to `addEventListener` without an parenthesis to stop the function being called at that point.

Comment: thanks alot for ur answer,but when i debug the execution stops at addEventListener and comes out,can u help me with this.

Comment: @user3535687 Have you tried clicking on the link to see if it works?

Comment: it says return undefined ,it is not executing the function block :(

Comment: I've set up a JSFiddle and it works fine: [Clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/9N6DC/)

Comment: It only displays the alert box if the input has `ALLUSERS` exactly. If it doesn't it does nothing.

Comment: it says link is null :(

Comment: Can I ask what browser you are using?

Comment: i am using mozilla,when i debug it does not enter the function block and says link is null

Comment: Oh of course, it has to be wrapped on a `window.onload` function, I'll edit it now.

Comment: an edited version would do a world of good.thanks alot :)

Comment: It will work fine now.

Comment: sorry to trouble you like this,its not working,am calling continueScript function on click of the submit button.its just coming out once it reaches window.onload = function(),where should i call this function and how.

Comment: `window.onload` makes the code within the function call when the document has loaded. Does it cause any errors? Are you using an updated version of Firefox?

Comment: the link is null,m confused how can it go wrong,i am fetching the link through id which exists

Comment: Is the link being added dynamically through JS or AJAX?

Comment: link is fine now,it says return undefined for the function.

Comment: So it doesn't display the alert box, the link is fine and the function returns `undefined` (normal for any function that does not explicitly return a value).

Answer (score 0):

Following code may work:

**EDITED:**

```
 <a href="blah1">blah1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a[href=blah1]').click(function() {
    var link = $(this); // here's your link.
    return false; // acts like the link was not clicked. return true to carry out the click.
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Won't this give `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`?

Comment: The question does not have a jQuery tag, as such a pure Javascript answer is inferred.

Comment: hold on guys it's one of the way where user can find button click event.Let me know from user, weather he/she used JQuery or not

Comment: If the question isn't tagged "jquery" and jQuery isn't mentioned you can assume the OP isn't currently using it. So if you want to recommend jQuery you should at least explain that the code you've shown uses it. Given the OP mentioned being new to JavaScript they may not have any idea what jQuery is...

Answer (score 0):

This executes your code when the button is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("report420").onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value == 'ALLUSERS') {
        document.getElementById("mainUserIdValue").value = "";
        alert("invalid input");
    }
}
```